# Code completion with introspective bindings

Tags: python, pydev, pycharm, gobject-introspection

I just started coding using the `GObject`, `GTK` and various other libraries in `gi.repository`, and because of import time introspective bindings, code completion doesn't really work in any IDE. Any method to make it work?

I use Pycharm in specific.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

for now you can use [fakegir](https://github.com/strycore/fakegir) in any IDE/Editor and in future a [bug fixed](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-6932) affected version in Pycharm